# Screen Sharing and video/audio calling using WebRTC

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, screensharing

I am able to share screen and Video/Audio calling using two different pages. i would like to merge this two pages. one way is to create two different connection for each. but how would i identify which stream belongs to screen sharing or Video/Audio calling?

thanks,
Krishna

Comment: on the success callback for grabbing the streams, simply store the stream ID and associate it with that type of stream.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent - Let say there two people. One person(initiator) would be sharing screen and video/audio. Second person would join the room. Second person would get two connections how would one identify which connection is for Screen Sharing or Video/audio.

Comment: you would have to indicate through your signalling server which SDP is for the which connection.